# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

i have 18.04 ubuntu.. When i try to upgrade it using sudo apt-get upgrade, i get the followin error message -

```
Removing oem-workaround-bluetooth-status (6) ...
sed: can't read /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oem-workaround-bluetooth-status (--remove):
 installed oem-workaround-bluetooth-status package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-workaround-bluetooth-status
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have many ideas. Not shure if one will work:

This add the file he is looking for:

```
sudo touch /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules
```

This one helps me often when i have such problems:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

will remove this package from your computer (but i assume it will not work without one of them above):

```
sudo apt remove oem-workaround-bluetooth-status
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. But now the bluetooth is disabled. How to enabled that please?

Comment: i ran all the three commands sequentially.

Comment: I get the following error if i try installing oem-workaround-bluetooth-status - Package oem-workaround-bluetooth-status is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oem-workaround-bluetooth-status' has no installation candidate

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-turn-on-off.html) will guid you how to enable bluetooth